# Ambiguous invocation of third party reference

Tags: c#, telerik

My code compiled perfectly until I added a new reference to my project. `Telerik.Windows.Controls.ScheduleView`

Once I added the reference, the error `ambiguous invocation` has started to appear to Dictionary Key Value Pairs.

> The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties:
>
> 'Telerik.Windows.Diagrams.Core.CommonExtensions.AddRange<System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string,object>>(System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string,object>>,
>   System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string,object>>)'
>
> and
>
> 'Telerik.Windows.Controls.CollectionExtensions.AddRange<System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string,object>>(System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string,object>>, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string,object>>)'

May I ask how do I resolve the ambiguous invocation for third party references.

My current code

```
var selectedTargetGroups = new Dictionary<string, object>();
selectedTargetGroups.AddRange(TargetGroups.Where(x => (int) x.Value == current.TargetGroupList.Id));
```

A way around this was to use .Add instead of AddRange. But any other alternative would be a great help.

Comment: `Dictionary` type also defined in the mentionioned `Telerik.Windows.Controls.ScheduleView`

Comment: I figured that much. But how can I specify which dictionary should be used?

Comment: Try this namespace: `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`

Comment: You should file a bug with Telerik, they shouldn't have multiple implementations of the same extension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no simple way to do this. If two extensions methods are in scope with equal signatures, there is no way to disambiguate between them short of explicitly specifying which implementation you want with the non-extensions syntax. In your example:

```
var selectedTargetGroups = new Dictionary<string, object>();
CollectionExtensions.AddRange(
   selectedTargetGroups, 
   TargetGroups.Where(x => (int) x.Value == current.TargetGroupList.Id)
);
```

Aside from being ugly and exposing the name of the class hosting the extension method (which might be subject to change), this is also no good if you have a lot of existing code you don't want to change this way.

Another workaround is to make sure the type containing whatever extension method you don't want isn't in scope. So rather than writing

```
using Telerik.Windows.Controls;
using Telerik.Windows.Diagrams.Core;
```

Be explicit about the types you want by using an alias:

```
using ScheduleView = Telerik.Windows.Controls.ScheduleView;
using Telerik.Windows.Diagrams.Core;
```

Obviously, this workaround can be very cumbersome if you do want all (or almost all) types in a namespace. Note that it is *not* possible to disambiguate extension methods by introducing aliases for the classes that hold them: extension methods on aliased types don't appear as extension methods. (They don't *disappear* either, so you can't "hide" unwanted extension methods this way.)

The best solution is to make sure this doesn't happen, but this requires cooperation from library writers. It's definitely a mistake to define a publicly accessible extension method on a type as general as `ICollection` in a library, because this just invites conflict. Extension methods should be defined only on types the library defines, or they should remain `internal` to the library, or they should be made part of their own namespace where they're available for selective import. This is no help to consumers of libraries that get it wrong, though.

Comment: Thank you for the indepth answer. I was  so puzzled on how to use CollectionExtensions method